# ZF2 - update user profile page

Tags: php, authentication, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am building a website using Zend Framework 2, managing authentication with ZfcUser. Now I'm working on a page where a registered user can update his profile data.

I noticed that even after the user updated his data via a form, and the data are written to the database, the method `getIdentity` of `Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService` still returns the old data because it stores them in session.

How can I get the new data without having to logout the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update has been successful:

```
$authenticationService->getStorage()->write($newIdentity);
```

Now you've updated your identity to match, however, I'd be very careful about a system that can dynamically shift identity. Identity should hopefully be unique and persistent. Not to say you CAN'T do it, but make sure you've covered your bases so no one can assume other identities.